how to show half pie with python pygal
In python with pygal, how to show half pie with pie_chart = pygal.Pie()?
I have typed the code
import pygal
pie_chart = pygal.Pie()

but I need to add some code in the pygal.Pie() to only show half pie. what should I type?

you can do it here: https://www.pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/types/solidgauge.html

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Read the Pie documentation, which has an example.
Demo:
import pygal
import os

pie = pygal.Pie(half_pie=True)
pie.title = 'Demo'
pie.add('A', 10)
pie.add('B', 20)
with open('out.html', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(pie.render())
os.startfile('out.html')

Output:


<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73" class="pygal-chart" viewBox="0 0 800 600"><!--Generated with pygal 3.0.5 (etree) ©Kozea 2012-2016 on 2024-09-30--><!--http://pygal.org--><!--http://github.com/Kozea/pygal--><defs><style type="text/css">#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73{-webkit-user-select:none;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;font-family:Consolas,"Liberation Mono",Menlo,Courier,monospace}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .title{font-family:Consolas,"Liberation Mono",Menlo,Courier,monospace;font-size:16px}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .legends .legend text{font-family:Consolas,"Liberation Mono",Menlo,Courier,monospace;font-size:14px}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .axis text{font-family:Consolas,"Liberation Mono",Menlo,Courier,monospace;font-size:10px}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .axis text.major{font-family:Consolas,"Liberation Mono",Menlo,Courier,monospace;font-size:10px}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .text-overlay text.value{font-family:Consolas,"Liberation Mono",Menlo,Courier,monospace;font-size:16px}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .text-overlay text.label{font-family:Consolas,"Liberation Mono",Menlo,Courier,monospace;font-size:10px}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .tooltip{font-family:Consolas,"Liberation Mono",Menlo,Courier,monospace;font-size:14px}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 text.no_data{font-family:Consolas,"Liberation Mono",Menlo,Courier,monospace;font-size:64px}
#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73{background-color:rgba(249,249,249,1)}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 path,#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 line,#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 rect,#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 circle{-webkit-transition:150ms;-moz-transition:150ms;transition:150ms}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .graph &gt; .background{fill:rgba(249,249,249,1)}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .plot &gt; .background{fill:rgba(255,255,255,1)}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .graph{fill:rgba(0,0,0,.87)}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 text.no_data{fill:rgba(0,0,0,1)}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .title{fill:rgba(0,0,0,1)}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .legends .legend text{fill:rgba(0,0,0,.87)}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .legends .legend:hover text{fill:rgba(0,0,0,1)}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .axis .line{stroke:rgba(0,0,0,1)}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .axis .guide.line{stroke:rgba(0,0,0,.54)}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .axis .major.line{stroke:rgba(0,0,0,.87)}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .axis text.major{fill:rgba(0,0,0,1)}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .axis.y .guides:hover .guide.line,#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .line-graph .axis.x .guides:hover .guide.line,#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .stackedline-graph .axis.x .guides:hover .guide.line,#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .xy-graph .axis.x .guides:hover .guide.line{stroke:rgba(0,0,0,1)}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .axis .guides:hover text{fill:rgba(0,0,0,1)}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .reactive{fill-opacity:.7;stroke-opacity:.8;stroke-width:1}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .ci{stroke:rgba(0,0,0,.87)}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .reactive.active,#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .active .reactive{fill-opacity:.8;stroke-opacity:.9;stroke-width:4}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .ci .reactive.active{stroke-width:1.5}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .series text{fill:rgba(0,0,0,1)}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .tooltip rect{fill:rgba(255,255,255,1);stroke:rgba(0,0,0,1);-webkit-transition:opacity 150ms;-moz-transition:opacity 150ms;transition:opacity 150ms}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .tooltip .label{fill:rgba(0,0,0,.87)}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .tooltip .label{fill:rgba(0,0,0,.87)}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .tooltip .legend{font-size:.8em;fill:rgba(0,0,0,.54)}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .tooltip .x_label{font-size:.6em;fill:rgba(0,0,0,1)}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .tooltip .xlink{font-size:.5em;text-decoration:underline}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .tooltip .value{font-size:1.5em}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .bound{font-size:.5em}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .max-value{font-size:.75em;fill:rgba(0,0,0,.54)}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .map-element{fill:rgba(255,255,255,1);stroke:rgba(0,0,0,.54) !important}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .map-element .reactive{fill-opacity:inherit;stroke-opacity:inherit}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .color-0,#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .color-0 a:visited{stroke:#F44336;fill:#F44336}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .color-1,#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .color-1 a:visited{stroke:#3F51B5;fill:#3F51B5}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .text-overlay .color-0 text{fill:black}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .text-overlay .color-1 text{fill:black}
#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 text.no_data{text-anchor:middle}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .guide.line{fill:none}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .centered{text-anchor:middle}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .title{text-anchor:middle}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .legends .legend text{fill-opacity:1}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .axis.x text{text-anchor:middle}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .axis.x:not(.web) text[transform]{text-anchor:start}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .axis.x:not(.web) text[transform].backwards{text-anchor:end}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .axis.y text{text-anchor:end}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .axis.y text[transform].backwards{text-anchor:start}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .axis.y2 text{text-anchor:start}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .axis.y2 text[transform].backwards{text-anchor:end}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .axis .guide.line{stroke-dasharray:4,4;stroke:black}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .axis .major.guide.line{stroke-dasharray:6,6;stroke:black}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .horizontal .axis.y .guide.line,#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .horizontal .axis.y2 .guide.line,#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .vertical .axis.x .guide.line{opacity:0}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .horizontal .axis.always_show .guide.line,#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .vertical .axis.always_show .guide.line{opacity:1 !important}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .axis.y .guides:hover .guide.line,#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .axis.y2 .guides:hover .guide.line,#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .axis.x .guides:hover .guide.line{opacity:1}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .axis .guides:hover text{opacity:1}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .nofill{fill:none}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .subtle-fill{fill-opacity:.2}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .dot{stroke-width:1px;fill-opacity:1;stroke-opacity:1}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .dot.active{stroke-width:5px}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .dot.negative{fill:transparent}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 text,#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 tspan{stroke:none !important}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .series text.active{opacity:1}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .tooltip rect{fill-opacity:.95;stroke-width:.5}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .tooltip text{fill-opacity:1}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .showable{visibility:hidden}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .showable.shown{visibility:visible}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .gauge-background{fill:rgba(229,229,229,1);stroke:none}#chart-6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73 .bg-lines{stroke:rgba(249,249,249,1);stroke-width:2px}</style><script type="text/javascript">window.pygal = window.pygal || {};window.pygal.config = window.pygal.config || {};window.pygal.config['6ca5e287-67c2-470c-8f8a-44527c806d73'] = {"allow_interruptions": false, "box_mode": "extremes", "classes": ["pygal-chart"], "css": ["file://style.css", "file://graph.css"], "defs": [], "disable_xml_declaration": false, "dots_size": 2.5, "dynamic_print_values": false, "explicit_size": false, "fill": false, "force_uri_protocol": "https", "formatter": null, "half_pie": true, "height": 600, "include_x_axis": false, "inner_radius": 0, "interpolate": null, "interpolation_parameters": {}, "interpolation_precision": 250, "inverse_y_axis": false, "js": ["//kozea.github.io/pygal.js/2.0.x/pygal-tooltips.min.js"], "legend_at_bottom": false, "legend_at_bottom_columns": null, "legend_box_size": 12, "logarithmic": false, "margin": 20, "margin_bottom": null, "margin_left": null, "margin_right": null, "margin_top": null, "max_scale": 16, "min_scale": 4, "missing_value_fill_truncation": "x", "no_data_text": "No data", "no_prefix": false, "order_min": null, "pretty_print": false, "print_labels": false, "print_values": false, "print_values_position": "center", "print_zeroes": true, "range": null, "rounded_bars": null, "secondary_range": null, "show_dots": true, "show_legend": true, "show_minor_x_labels": true, "show_minor_y_labels": true, "show_only_major_dots": false, "show_x_guides": false, "show_x_labels": true, "show_y_guides": true, "show_y_labels": true, "spacing": 10, "stack_from_top": false, "strict": false, "stroke": true, "stroke_style": null, "style": {"background": "rgba(249, 249, 249, 1)", "ci_colors": [], "colors": ["#F44336", "#3F51B5", "#009688", "#FFC107", "#FF5722", "#9C27B0", "#03A9F4", "#8BC34A", "#FF9800", "#E91E63", "#2196F3", "#4CAF50", "#FFEB3B", "#673AB7", "#00BCD4", "#CDDC39", "#9E9E9E", "#607D8B"], "dot_opacity": "1", "font_family": "Consolas, \"Liberation Mono\", Menlo, Courier, monospace", "foreground": "rgba(0, 0, 0, .87)", "foreground_strong": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)", "foreground_subtle": "rgba(0, 0, 0, .54)", "guide_stroke_color": "black", "guide_stroke_dasharray": "4,4", "label_font_family": "Consolas, \"Liberation Mono\", Menlo, Courier, monospace", "label_font_size": 10, "legend_font_family": "Consolas, \"Liberation Mono\", Menlo, Courier, monospace", "legend_font_size": 14, "major_guide_stroke_color": "black", "major_guide_stroke_dasharray": "6,6", "major_label_font_family": "Consolas, \"Liberation Mono\", Menlo, Courier, monospace", "major_label_font_size": 10, "no_data_font_family": "Consolas, \"Liberation Mono\", Menlo, Courier, monospace", "no_data_font_size": 64, "opacity": ".7", "opacity_hover": ".8", "plot_background": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)", "stroke_opacity": ".8", "stroke_opacity_hover": ".9", "stroke_width": "1", "stroke_width_hover": "4", "title_font_family": "Consolas, \"Liberation Mono\", Menlo, Courier, monospace", "title_font_size": 16, "tooltip_font_family": "Consolas, \"Liberation Mono\", Menlo, Courier, monospace", "tooltip_font_size": 14, "transition": "150ms", "value_background": "rgba(229, 229, 229, 1)", "value_colors": [], "value_font_family": "Consolas, \"Liberation Mono\", Menlo, Courier, monospace", "value_font_size": 16, "value_label_font_family": "Consolas, \"Liberation Mono\", Menlo, Courier, monospace", "value_label_font_size": 10}, "title": "Demo", "tooltip_border_radius": 0, "tooltip_fancy_mode": true, "truncate_label": null, "truncate_legend": null, "width": 800, "x_label_rotation": 0, "x_labels": null, "x_labels_major": null, "x_labels_major_count": null, "x_labels_major_every": null, "x_title": null, "xrange": null, "y_label_rotation": 0, "y_labels": null, "y_labels_major": null, "y_labels_major_count": null, "y_labels_major_every": null, "y_title": null, "zero": 0, "legends": ["A", "B"]}</script><script type="text/javascript" xlink:href="https://kozea.github.io/pygal.js/2.0.x/pygal-tooltips.min.js" /></defs><title>Demo</title><g class="graph pie-graph vertical"><rect x="0" y="0" width="800" height="600" class="background" /><g transform="translate(50, 46)" class="plot"><rect x="0" y="0" width="729.6" height="534" class="background" /><g class="series serie-0 color-0"><g class="slices"><g class="slice"><path d="M36.480000 427.200000 A328.320000 328.320000 0 0 1 200.640000 142.866539 L364.800000 427.200000 A0.000000 0.000000 0 0 0 364.800000 427.200000 z" class="slice reactive tooltip-trigger" /><desc class="value">10</desc><desc class="x centered">222.63326971474658</desc><desc class="y centered">345.12</desc></g></g></g><g class="series serie-1 color-1"><g class="slices"><g class="slice"><path d="M200.640000 142.866539 A328.320000 328.320000 0 0 1 693.120000 427.200000 L364.800000 427.200000 A0.000000 0.000000 0 0 0 364.800000 427.200000 z" class="slice reactive tooltip-trigger" /><desc class="value">20</desc><desc class="x centered">446.8799999999999</desc><desc class="y centered">285.03326971474644</desc></g></g></g></g><g class="titles"><text x="400.0" y="26" class="title plot_title">Demo</text></g><g transform="translate(50, 46)" class="plot overlay"><g class="series serie-0 color-0" /><g class="series serie-1 color-1" /></g><g transform="translate(50, 46)" class="plot text-overlay"><g class="series serie-0 color-0" /><g class="series serie-1 color-1" /></g><g transform="translate(50, 46)" class="plot tooltip-overlay"><g transform="translate(0 0)" style="opacity: 0" class="tooltip"><rect rx="0" ry="0" width="0" height="0" class="tooltip-box" /><g class="text" /></g></g><g transform="translate(10, 56)" class="legends"><g id="activate-serie-0" class="legend reactive activate-serie"><rect x="0.0" y="1.0" width="12" height="12" class="color-0 reactive" /><text x="17.0" y="11.2">A</text></g><g id="activate-serie-1" class="legend reactive activate-serie"><rect x="0.0" y="22.0" width="12" height="12" class="color-1 reactive" /><text x="17.0" y="32.2">B</text></g></g><g transform="translate(790, 56)" class="legends" /></g></svg>



